# Disable mobile scroll on google map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, mobile

I'm using the WP Google map plugin for my site. When I use my finger to scroll down the mobile page on an iPhone, once I get to the map, the page scrolling is overridden and the map starts panning. The only way for me to scroll farther down the page is to put my finger above or below the map, assuming such space is available.

Is there a way to solution to this? Something along the lines of disabling the mobile scroll?

Link: http://zaaroinfotechsolutions.com/zaarodemo/longbeach/contact-us/

Answer (score 1):

You should deactivate scroll when initiating the map:

```
var mapOptions = {
        // ...
        scrollwheel: false,
        // ...
    };
```

Then you can control whether to make the map draggable or not by getting the width of the layout like:

```
var drag = $(document).width() > 640 ? true : false;
var mapOptions = {
            // ...
            isDraggable: drag,
            scrollwheel: false,
            // ...
        };
```

Furthermore, if you want to maintain map navigation functionality in mobile devices, you can do it by setting the `panControl` - `bool`, true or false - property in your `mapOptions`.

### Edit: Passing the mapOptions on init

**HTML**

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    // ... your existent init code
    isDraggable: drag,
    scrollwheel: false,
    // ...
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: I added an example so you can get an idea, however i encourage you to read [Google Maps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). Please accept the answer if it did help you.